# Visual Studio Code with Coderunner extnsion outputting UTF-8 as?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Im using Visual Studio Code with Powershell extension and CodeRunner extension.

Any idea what I have to configure for CodeRunner to stop outputting ? ([Ausgabe UTF8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJbto.png)). In Background it works fine. Can I configure the Output View?

The only thing that I found was with python:

```
{
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "python": "chcp 65001 | py"
    }
}
```

But I don't think this works with powershell?

The settings.json is has the following in it:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Tomorrow Night Blue",
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell" ,
    "[powershell]":                           
    {
        "files.encoding": "utf8bom",
    },
    "[code-runner.executorMap]":{
        "powershell": "pwsh -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File",
    }
}
```

---------------------- Additional Information -------------------

Have found an Workaround for Powershell.

```
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::UTF8
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Encoding'] = 'utf8'
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding'] = 'utf8'
```

[Work only for Powershell but not for CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUQiT.png)

but not for and CMD command like dsquery. (the data that you see is not real.;) only a test)

Under Windows 10 since 1809 you can set this:

[Work only under Windows 10 since 1809](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuxK5.png)

Should fix it. But Windows Server 2016 Haven't this Option.

Comment: For PowerShell it can help to save script files as UTF8BOM. There is some weird dynamic with PowerShell reading scripts that are just UTF8 and falling back to ASCI/CodePage. See [Understanding file encoding in VS Code and PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/vscode/understanding-file-encoding?view=powershell-7.2). You could try to set `"files.encoding": "utf8bom"`. This willo not affect cmd.

Comment: I read your link ;) your suggestion i have tested. Doesn't work :(

Comment: https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/887 here you can see the probleme better @Seth

Comment: This might be the best you can do. I'm not sure how CodeRunner is invoked by VSCode that might also be responsible for the issue. If it is some arcane `cmd` be invoked or whatever that might explain the issue. Though it would feel dirty you could try to let powershell output in CP-1252 instead of UTF8. That might get you "correct" output that will break in other situation. If it's specifically `dsquery` you need you could just have a look at the AD PS cmdlets like [`Get-ADObject`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adobject?view=windowsserver2019-ps).

Comment: Ok i try Get-ADObject to Use i think . I make a study in Informatik and there i should learn it with dsquery combined with powershell. The Powershell things are less information in that book i have. So i find lots out of myselfe. In Background it works now with all. But on display not this time. Thanks for information.